# How to use an ActionBar with an ExpandableListView in the same Activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, expandablelistview

I'm trying to use a ExpandableListView with an ActionBar in the same activity. I don't really know how to use both at the same time because of I can't extend my class to ExplandableListActivity and ActionBarActivity together.

Does anybody know how to fix that problem?

Thanks!!

Comment: Update to the [latest Support Library (v22.1.0)](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) and refer to [`AppCompatDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html), *"a delegate which you can use to extend AppCompat's support to any `Activity`."* Alternatively, don't use `ExpandableListViewActivity`, but include an `ExpandableListView` in your layout and call the relevant methods on it directly.

Comment: Or, do not use `ExpandableListActivity`. You do not need to use `ExpandableListActivity` to use an `ExpandableListView`, just as you do not need to use `ListActivity` to use a `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I tried it extending of ActionBarActivity and it works at the moment!

I'm going to copy the code here if anybody needs it, I've used a part of code from a how to tutorial. The MainActivity is:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        ExpandableListView expandableList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.explist);

        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("Android");
        parentItems.add("Core Java");
        parentItems.add("Desktop Java");
        parentItems.add("Enterprise Java");
    }

    public void setChildData() {

        // Android
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Core");
        child.add("Games");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Core Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Apache");
        child.add("Applet");
        child.add("AspectJ");
        child.add("Beans");
        child.add("Crypto");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Desktop Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Accessibility");
        child.add("AWT");
        child.add("ImageIO");
        child.add("Print");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Enterprise Java
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("EJB3");
        child.add("GWT");
        child.add("Hibernate");
        child.add("JSP");
        childItems.add(child);
    }
}
```

The adapter:

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition)+" holaaa",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The layout activity_home.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/explist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout group.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the layout row.xml:

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#F5F9F2"
    />
```

Thank you all!